# How to avoid similiar queries in for loop in django template

Tags: sql, django

I have code with 2 for loops in django template which iterate my model and show info in template from that model

But for some reason Debugger show me that i have similiar queries  in my second for loop and i dont know how to avoid that

template.html

```
{% for info_list in details_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ info_list.presence_info.object_presence }}</td>
        <td>{{ info_list.presence_info.counter_presence }}</td>
        <td>{{ info_list.work_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ info_list.amount_of_workers }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for sections in info_list.parts_with_sections.all %}
                {{ sections.presence_sections.name }} |
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```py
class PresenceListInfo(models.Model):
    object_presence = models.ForeignKey(ObjectList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Объект', default=None,
                                        null=True)

    counter_presence = models.ForeignKey(CounterParty, verbose_name='Контрагенты', default=None, null=True,
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class PresenceDetailInfo(models.Model):
    presence_info = models.ForeignKey(PresenceListInfo, verbose_name='Объекты', default=None, null=True,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details_info')

    work_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата', default=None)

    amount_of_workers = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество работников', default=0)

    def parts_with_sections(self):
        return self.presence_sections_list.select_related('presence_sections')


class PresenceSectionList(models.Model):
    presence_detail = models.ForeignKey(PresenceDetailInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        related_name='presence_sections_list')
    presence_sections = models.ForeignKey(CleanSections, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```py
class ShowPresenceInfoList(ListView):
    model = PresenceDetailInfo
    template_name = 'common/presence_info.html'
    context_object_name = 'details_list'
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues adding [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to queryset will solve your problem

```py
class ShowPresenceInfoList(ListView):
    model = PresenceDetailInfo
    template_name = 'common/presence_info.html'
    context_object_name = 'details_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('presence_sections_list__presence_sections')
```

And changing template loop on `presence_sections_list`

```
{% for sections in info_list.presence_sections_list.all %}
```

Comment: for some reason it just added 2 more queries

Comment: and if you change your loop in template on `{% for sections in info_list.presence_sections_list.all %}` ?